# Read multiple queries in jena tdb using command line?

Tags: sparql, jena

I am able to execute one query at a time but not all that are in the file. Queries are generated from SP2 Benchmark and are separated by / delimiter.

Comment: afaik, there is no built-in command in Jena. you can easily do this via any kind of script, Python, bash, batch, whatever - this is trival do do.

Comment: and what is the use-case? do you need the result of each query? or do you want to run some benchmark? if yes, most benchmarking frameworks also have so-called "benchmark runners". if there is no such runner, just as I said before, write a small script.